# python keyError at JSON parsing

Tags: python, json, google-books

I am trying to use Google Books Python API Client. Here is my simple code snippet:

```
for book in response.get('items', []):
    if not book['volumeInfo']['title'] or not book['volumeInfo']['authors']:
        continue
    else:
        print 'Title: %s, Author: %s' % (book['volumeInfo']['title'], book['volumeInfo']['authors'])
```

I am trying to get metadata from a list of books based on a keyword. However,  It gives me

```
KeyError: 'authors'
```

I checked and found out that the JSON response does not have an "authors" field for a specific book. I tried to skip that book with the if else statement above, but it didn't work. How can I avoid from such errors when there isn't a field in the JSON response as I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dict.get()` method to retrieve a default, or you can use membership testing to see if the key is there at all:

```
for book in response.get('items', []):
    if 'title' not in book['volumeInfo'] or 'authors' not in book['volumeInfo']:
        continue
    print 'Title: %s, Author: %s' % (book['volumeInfo']['title'], book['volumeInfo']['authors'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `get` method of dictionaries to pull your keys out. You can set a default incase the key doesn't exist:

```
book.get('volumeInfo', default=None)
```